# Field has incomplete type when building with NDK

Tags: c++, stl, android-ndk

I have a class that contains references to children, as an unordered map of itself. Which can be distilled down to this example:

```
struct test_struct {
  std::unordered_map<std::string,test_struct> _children;
};
```

This has been compiling using the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler as well as on OSX using XCode's (llvm).

But now I am trying to build my project for Android using the NDK which uses gnu c++, which complains

```
/NVPACK/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/bits/stl_pair.h(102,11) :  error: field has incomplete type 'test_struct'
...
note: definition of 'test_struct' is not complete until the closing '}'
```

Comment: with ndk-r11c, and **APP_STL=c++_static**, your `struct` compiles.

Comment: It works with `std::map` though. Seems like a bug!